# How do you use an unbound property as the argument of an if helper in a template with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a Handlebars helper that takes a number and returns a class name. I want to run the helper only if `foobar` exists because it might not exist. My initial attempt was:

```
{{#each content}}
    <div class="other_class {{#if foobar}}{{my_helper foobar}}{{/if}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

This doesn't work because metamorph inserts script tag placeholders where the `if` helper is. My second attempt was:

```
{{#each content}}
    <div class="other_class {{my_helper foobar}}"></div>
{{/each}}
```

This also doesn't work because when foobar does not exist, the string `"foobar"` is passed to `my_helper`.

I know that doing `{{unbound foobar}}` will render the value without binding it and thus without script tag placeholders. Is there a way to use `if` in an unbound way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a computed property and add it to `classNameBindings` of a view, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/MvpUZ/:

```js
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: 'omg'.w(),

    omg: function(){
        var foobar = Ember.getPath(this, 'content.foobar');
        return (foobar && foobar === 42) ? 'my-class-name' : null;
    }.property('content.foobar')
});
```

Comment: This works, but I would prefer something like `{{#unboundif foo}}{{/unboundif}}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper for this. It's called `unboundIf`: see [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unboundIf)

You can use it like this:

```
{{#unboundIf "content.shouldDisplayTitle"}}
  {{content.title}}
{{/unboundIf}}
```

The expression is only evaluated once.